# Sum a one to many based on multiple criteria and JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I'm not sure how to word my question. But I have 2 different tables that need to join together to give results.

```
Table A
--------------------------
Id  |  Field_Id |  Value
--------------------------
1234|     16    |   PO456
1234|      7    |   40
1334|     16    |   PO456
1334|      7    |   20
1246|     16    |   PO679
1246|      7    |   100
1247|     16    |   PO679
1247|      7    |   20
1247|     16    |   PO679
1247|      7    |   40


Table B
--------------
Id  |  Hours | 
--------------
1234|   2
1234|   3
1234|   4
1234|   5
1334|   8
1334|   8
1334|   8
1246|   3
1246|   3
1247|   8
1247|   8
```

Now the Result I want should look like this.

```
Result
-----------------------
Value  |  Est |  Hours
-----------------------
PO456  |   60 |   38
PO679  |   160|   22
```

Here is my sql:

```
select a.value as "Id", CAST(sum(d.value) AS Decimal(10,2)) as 'Est' 
, COALESCE(sum(b.Hours),0) as "Hours"

from table_a a 
left Join table_b b ON a.Id = b.Id
inner join table_a d ON d.Id = a.Id AND d.Field_Id = '7'
where a.Field_Id =  '16' and a.value <> ' ' 
Group By a.value
ORDER BY a.value  ASC
```

Now my hours column comes in correctly, however it's the Est column that comes back with strange data, like the numbers are thousands off. Is it not being tied back to the first column somehow? I basically want to get a sum of all Id's with that same a.value on one line. My work around right now is it displays all Id's and there are simply multiple Values and it's broken down individually. However, I want it condensed. Any assistance would be appreciated. If there are minor spelling errors in my code (this isn't the actual code, the code is simply renamed privacy reasons, I need help on the logic). Please and thank you.

Comment: The column Value can't be sum()-ed, since it's not a numeric column. The query is invalid and should raise an error.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh That's why I'm casting it as a decimal. The query works, just the value return doesn't.

Comment: You cast the sum, not the values. Do sum(cast(d.value as  Decimal(10,2)) instead.

Comment: @jarlh this didn't give a different result. The numbers are still inaccurate.

Comment: If you SUM() the values PO456 and 40, what result do you expect?

Comment: @jarlh, those two values won't be summed together. They are attached to a different field_id. It will only summed the 40 with another number.

Comment: @jarlh to answer your earlier question. It's MySQL, I'm running the queries from phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

What a confusing data model!  You can do this with a subquery to get the `est` value:

```
select a16.value, a7.value, 
       sum(b.hours)  
from table_a a16 left join
     (select a16.value,
             sum(a7.value) as est    -- should convert to a number for sum()
      from table_a a16 join
           table_a a7
           on a16.id = a7.id and a7.field_id = 7 and
              a16.field_id = 16
      group by 16.value
     ) a7
     on a16.value = a7.value
     table_b b 
     on a16.Id = b.Id
where a16.field_id = 16
group by a16.value, a7.est;
```

Comment: I put this in, but now all values are Null for the Est column

Comment: sorry I took the group by out and it only returned 1 single record, which is also what I don't want. I want all the different ones. But I didn't receive a syntax error. Just a column that says NULL in it.

Comment: @dcary . . . It should WORK with the `group by`.